# SQL : subquery limited to 1 but shows up 3

Tags: sql

Can someone please explain how the following code works? I am beyond confused. I don't understand how the "last_null" and "first_null" column that was limited to 1 but somehow has 3 rows.

[[image: the goal of the problem]

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    anonymous_id AS 'anonym_id',
    (SELECT event_name
     FROM tracks b
     WHERE b.anonymous_id = a.anonymous_id 
       AND b.user_id IS NULL
     ORDER BY received_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS 'last_null',
    (SELECT event_name
     FROM tracks b
     WHERE b.anonymous_id = a.anonymous_id 
       AND b.user_id IS NOT NULL
     ORDER BY received_at ASC LIMIT 1) AS 'first_notnull'
FROM 
    tracks a 
ORDER BY 
    a.anonymous_id;
```

[[image: code]

Comment: The `limit` is not affecting the overall result of 3 distinct rows for the Ids, these are *correlated subqueries* and have to be limited to 1 row - that means "give me one row (the first when ordered by `received_at`) for *each* row in the main (outer) query"

Answer (score 1):

This is the "core" query

```
SELECT DISTINCT anonymous_id as 'anonym_id'
FROM tracks a 
ORDER BY a.anonymous_id;
```

It could produce any number of rows (none to a great many, depends on the data in table `tracks`).

The balance of the query is adding COLUMNS to the output, not rows, and I believe this helps to emphasise the usefulness/necessity of indentation when formatting code e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      anonymous_id AS "anonym_id"
    , (
        SELECT event_name
        FROM tracks b
        WHERE b.anonymous_id = a.anonymous_id
            AND b.user_id IS NULL
        ORDER BY received_at DESC LIMIT 1
        ) AS "last_null"
    , (
        SELECT event_name
        FROM tracks b
        WHERE b.anonymous_id = a.anonymous_id
            AND b.user_id IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY received_at ASC LIMIT 1
        ) AS "first_notnull"
FROM tracks a
ORDER BY a.anonymous_id;
```

nb: I prefer a "comma first" approach to formatting SQL

In the second and third columns, the query is using "[correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)" which will return up to one value only, for each row of data that the "core query" will return.